# Setting replyTo field in email

Tags: php, email

I have an SMTP question. I have created a PHP script to send out emails. The requirement is that I need to send email from 'email1@example.com' but I need replies to come to 'email2@example.com'

I have added `email2@example.com` in the `reply-to` header field. The only problem I am having is that when someone receives the email and clicks on the reply button, both `email1@example.com` and `email2@example.com` are being shown in the `TO` field.

Is there any way that I can have `email1@example.com` removed from the TO field and only show the email address that was specified in the `reply-to` field?

I am using PHPMailer and the code is below:

```
    $this->phpmailer->IsSMTP();
    $this->phpmailer->Host = $server;
    $this->phpmailer->Port = $port;
    $this->phpmailer->SetFrom($fromEmail, $fromName); //this is email1@example.com
    $this->phpmailer->AddReplyTo($replyEmail,$fromName);  //this is email2@example.com
    $this->phpmailer->Subject = $subject;
    $this->phpmailer->AltBody = $msgTXT; // non-html text
    $this->phpmailer->MsgHTML($msgHTML); // html body-text
    $this->phpmailer->AddAddress($email);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->phpmailer->IsSMTP();
$this->phpmailer->Host = $server;
$this->phpmailer->Port = $port;
$this->phpmailer->AddReplyTo($replyEmail,$fromName);  //this is email2@example.com
$this->phpmailer->SetFrom($fromEmail, $fromName); //this is email1@example.com
$this->phpmailer->Subject = $subject;
$this->phpmailer->MsgHTML($msgHTML); // html body-text
$this->phpmailer->AddAddress($email);
```

Try setting AddReplyTo() first before SetFrom. phpmailer needs to change this behavior. It adds the from address to the reply-to field. If you set reply-to first before the from address, it will not be able to add your from address to the reply-to header.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I will check it and let you know how it goes

Comment: yeah but it's kind of a "hack" so you don't need to edit phpmailer. If you just need to send a normal email, you can also stop using phpmailer completely and do this:

mail('email1@example.com','mail subject','the email body',"From: from.address@example.com\nReply-to: the.reply@address.here");

but your server must be configured to use mail().

Comment: Just to note, the call to $this->phpmailer->MsgHTML($msgHTML) sets the AltBody at the same time, so will effectively wipe out the AltBody set in the previous line

Answer (score -1):

[From a google search and first result](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#Adding_Reply-To)

> Adding a Reply-To Address ^
>
> By default the Reply-To address will be the FROM address unless you specify otherwise. That is simply E-Mail client intelligence. However, you can have the E-Mail come from one E-Mail address and any replies go to a different one. Here's how:
>
> `$mailer->AddReplyTo('billing@yourdomain.com', 'Billing Department');`
>
> NOTE:
>   You can have multiple Reply-To addresses, just duplicate the line in the previous code example and change the E-Mail address on each line.

You will need to add this line before your from address.  P[lease check out this for the solution to the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396264/phpmailer-reply-using-only-reply-to-address)

Following these examples, your code should look like

```
$this->phpmailer->IsSMTP();
$this->phpmailer->Host = $server;
$this->phpmailer->Port = $port;
$this->phpmailer->AddReplyTo($replyEmail,$fromName);  //this is email2@example.com
$this->phpmailer->SetFrom($fromEmail, $fromName); //this is email1@example.com
$this->phpmailer->Subject = $subject;
$this->phpmailer->AltBody = $msgTXT; // non-html text
$this->phpmailer->MsgHTML($msgHTML); // html body-text
$this->phpmailer->AddAddress($email);
```