# phpmailer: Reply using only “Reply To” address does not work

Tags: php, phpmailer

Am using phpmailer to automate mails in a webapp I am writing. Even after adding replyto it is adding both the from and replyto ids into the "Reply To" field and when the reply button is used to reply to the mail in the email client the from address is automatically added in the "To" address of the reply. I have tried using the solution as detailed in [phpmailer: Reply using only "Reply To" address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396264/phpmailer-reply-using-only-reply-to-address) . But that is also not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$mail->Password   = USER_PASSWORD;
        $mail->AddReplyTo("xxx@yyy.org","abc");
        $mail->SetFrom("$from","$fromname");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
```

Comment: Please provide your current non-functioning code.

Comment: There is no need for double quotes around the php variables $from and $fromname. (by the way i gues this won't solve the problem)

Comment: Okay, now show us the headers from the mail that this generates.

Comment: Did you try to use the last version of phpmailer? I checked the class' code and noticed that the problem issued from the link you posted has already been solved.

Comment: Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = true` to have debug logging output which you can use to see if there are any errors. could be your smtp server stripping them out.

Comment: Have checked up the debugging log output and there are no errors present

Comment: The problem is solved. Tried changing the From and To Addresses and made them different. Then it started working. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Please check your "AddReplyTo" and "SetFrom" email id was different or not??