# PHPMailer not working with gmail (using xampp localhost)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've been using phpmailer for a contact form recently, but when I try to send the contact form to the email it results into an error. Any help will be appreciated! Keep in mind that this is using xampp localhost. Also my contact.php redirects to another page which ma My error is

> 2016-02-21 00:02:19   Invalid address: (addAnAddress Reply-To): 11 
>   Notice: Undefined property: PHPMailer::$send in C:\xampp\htdocs\Guild
>   Website\contact.php on line 51

Contact.php script is also -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['ign'], $_POST['gamepref'], $_POST['cps'], $_POST['anythingelse'])) {

$fields = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'e-mail' => $_POST['email'],
    'IGN' => $_POST['ign'],
    'game preference' => $_POST['gamepref'],
    'CPS' => $_POST['cps'],
    'anything else' => $_POST['anythingelse'],
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)) {
        $errors[] = "The $field field is required."; 
    }
}

if(empty($errors)) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Username = 'somemail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'pass';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->isHTML();

    $mail->Subject = '$fields[\'name\'] is wanting to apply.';
    $mail->Body = '<p>Name: $fields[\'name\']</p><p>E-Mail: $fields[\'e-mail\']</p><p>IGN: $fields[\'IGN\']</p><p>Game Preference: $fields[\'game preference\']</p><p>CPS: $fields[\'CPS\']</p><p>Message: $fields[\'anything else\']</p>';

    $mail->FromName = 'Contact';

    $mail->AddReplyTo($fields['e-mail'], $fields['name']);

    $mail->AddAddress('somemail@gmail.com');

    if($mail->send) {
        header('Location: thanks.php');
        die();
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.';
    }
}

} else {
$errors[] = "Something went wrong! (Mabye it is because you didn't put anything!)";
}
$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: How do I check? I tried using $mai;->SMTPDebug = 2; but I have no idea how to view the message.

Comment: Put this at the top of your file: ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Ok, and do you have any errors in your $SESSION['errors'] variable?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I actually just cancelled the redirection to the page error.php, and came with the error of: 2016-02-21 00:02:19 Invalid address: (addAnAddress Reply-To): 11 
Notice: Undefined property: PHPMailer::$send in C:\xampp\htdocs\Guild Website\contact.php on line 51

Comment: Shouldn't $mail->send be $mail->Send()?

Comment: Just tried that, but I return with the error:

2016-02-21 00:19:02 Invalid address: (addAnAddress Reply-To): 11 2016-02-21 00:19:06 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2016-02-21 00:19:06 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting


by the ways, thank you so much for the help! I'm glad to see that this community is great.

Comment: Looking at similar questions, try the solution to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396264/phpmailer-reply-using-only-reply-to-address)

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. I put debugging set to 4 and am starting to get the error of -

2016-02-21 00:31:02 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2016-02-21 00:31:02 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2016-02-21 00:31:02 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: My last shot at it, try port 25

Comment: That didn't work, but thank's for the help! Have a good night/day.

Comment: `send` is a function, not a variable, and you're getting an invalid address error because you're giving it an invalid address. Don't redirect while debugging, it just gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out a solution! First I switched over to tls, then I added this - 
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    and finally allowed less secure apps for gmail.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem posted, and is a bad idea anyway.